# Running out of memory

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, ubuntu-18.04

Shared memory reported by free command is constantly raising while available memory is going down to 0. Understood that Linux is using free ram for disk caching but even after running drop_caches shared memory usage remains very high. after 1-2 days system starts swapping and becomes really slow!

```
$ grep Shmem /proc/meminfo
Shmem:           4922540 kB
ShmemHugePages: 0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped: 0 kB

$ df -BK | grep tmpfs
tmpfs                                  1608216K       3268K   1604948K    1% /run
tmpfs                                  8041060K         12K   8041048K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                     5120K          4K      5116K    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                                  8041060K          0K   8041060K    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                                  1608212K         16K   1608196K    1% /run/user/120
tmpfs                                  1608212K          0K   1608212K    0% /run/user/1000

$ free -m
              Gesamt   belegt    frei        gemns. Puffer/Cache verfügbar
Speicher:       15705         494        4220        4807       10990       10069
Auslagerungsspeicher:        8099           3        8096
```

how can I see why shared is increasing & what's in there?

i've configured gitlab to use prometheus and enabled node_exporter so i get insights of memory usage. you can clearly see around 250MB increasing every 20 minutes at hh:13, hh:33 and hh:53.

[prometheus node_exporter inactive anon over time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5T9d.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that gnome-shell ist crashing every 20minutes. System used as headless homeserver but connected to 4k TV via HDMI (TV Off all the time). Display Scaling Set to 200% in User Session.

System: H370 / i915 / i3-8100.

I disconnected the HDMI cable and at least for now it's looking good!

[Output off dmesg | grep gnome-shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gyi3G.png)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently some program is looping on the creation of shared memory segments.
These segments cannot be swapped out of memory, so the available RAM is eaten up,
thus causing swaps.

For identifying the product, see the article
[How to identify which program is using the share memory and when did it used it](http://fibrevillage.com/sysadmin/229-how-to-identify-which-program-is-using-the-share-memory-and-when-did-it-used-it).

The short summary is :

1. Use `ipcs -m` to get shared memory segment info

[image: image1]

2. Use `ipcs -mp` to show which PID is using (or used) the shared memory segment

[image: image2]

3. Use `ps -p` to search the pid info

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing these instructions. I've completed the instructions and shutdown a running gitlab instance as gitlab-psql and postgres showed up there. However shared memory usage still remains high and increases every 20-30 minutes.

Comment: You may have to keep on searching, or gitlab may restart by itself.

Comment: did that, updated my initial post with a prometheus node_exporter graph showing regular increasing inactive anon size. any chance to see what is running periodically here? nothing within crontab as far as i know

Comment: I don't understand why the above the procedure doesn't help you find out the guilty process. Shared memory cannot exist without being used, as it's destroyed whenever its last user closes it or the process terminates.

Comment: Has been related to gnome-shell crashing every 20 minutes. (See other answer)